# 2D Fourier transform of periodic structure showing frequencies lower than fundamental frequencies

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Is there a possibility that there appears a maxima in the fourier space (in the absolute value of the transform) of a purely periodic structure. I was of the impression that purely periodic structures could not have a local maxima at frequencies lower than the fundamental frequency of the structure

[image]
The image shown above has hexagonal symmetry and is supposed to be hexagonally symmetric. It's fourier transform is shown in the image below
[image]

The white spots shown below are the fundamental frequencies of the periodicity of the structure. But, we also see other spots (pink) at frequencies lower than the fundamental frequency (white spots). Why do these frequencies occur? Or are they simply maxima/minimas?

Any and all help is appreciated.

P.S. the sampling matrix of the image file(first image) for sure will not see pure periodicity since the sampling lattice is square in shape while the image periodicity is hexagonal.

Comment: I just saw your question. A first reaction. Let us call $C$ the 2D Dirac comb made with the *vertices* of your honeycomb. Let $H$ be the basic hexagon. Then your question amounts to understand the F. Transform $F.T.(C \star H)$ where $\star$ is for convolution, i.e., understand the product $FT(C).FT(H)$. The spurious pink dots are due to this $FT(H)$ but also due to the truncation (the hexagonal grid is truncated by a square window). This is a reason to look for an exact expression for $FT(H)$ which shouldn't be too difficult. Think also to work on the logarithm of the modulus of the image...

Comment: @JeanMarie But, I always though that abrupt truncation(as in bad windowing) would generally lead to signal leakage and broadening of the spots "present at the position of the  harmonics". Do you have experience which suggests that abrupt windows can cause "new spots" to appear??

Comment: I have some experience on practical applications of F.T. in image processing. If I have some time, I will maybe give you more precision.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks a lot. Iwould be indebted. After all, we can see because we stand on the shoulders of people like you.

Comment: ... I appreciate your humor (besides, is it Newton who used this expression ?)

Comment: @JeanMarie  I'm not sure of the source, but I was taken aback by how true the statement is and was aghast as to why it wasn't said more often.